# Div Height help, child elements position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the div have a height of 100% with the controls inside it having position absolute without setting divParents height to xxx px? I tried to wrap everything inside divParent in another div and I got the same results.

Example.

```
    <div style="border: solid 1px black; position: relative;" id="divParent">

    <span style="position: absolute; top: 177px; left: 41px">Name</span>
    <input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 253px; left: 36px; height: 18px;
    width: 342px;" />
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 229px; left: 38px">Address</span>
    <input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 199px; left: 39px; height: 18px;
    width: 342px;"/>

    </div>
```

Comment: otherwise (if you want to stick to plain css and no js): is there another way for you to display the div (without position:absolute)?

Comment: No, the controls in the div are coming from other web pages. What I am doing is merging web pages for printing using XMLHttpRequest and am adding the body that returns from the XMLHttpRequest into a div. That part is working fine, but I know have to add a span at the end of the div and am having trouble placing it at the bottom of the div since all of the controls have position absolute.

Comment: why does it have to be a span? spans behave differently than divs (divs are display:block as standard)... if you use float inside the mother div and only divs, not spans, this might work, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned items are no longer part of the layout. The parent has no idea how big they are, or where that are, so it cannot automatically re-size itself to accommodate them.

You can write your own JavaScript to calculate all of this, but CSS alone cannot do what you want.

Comment: I was looking into writing a javascript function to loop through the elements in the div and then find the greatest top, but did not know how the performance hit would be if there are 100 + elements in the div.

Comment: Try it and see. It won't be too bad if you use jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, but it looks as you output some kind of html form. Anyway, you could also only use `margin-top` and `margin-left` together with `float-left` inside your mother div (which you can position however you want, relative or absolute)...